# how do i generate random number loop with fix char code in c#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, gridview, random, ascii

I have tried to generate the six digit random number in which first three numbers are changing with random number and last three digit is in number which is amount and converted in to ascii to character now problem is i want to generate every time new code with three new digit and three fix digit which i had entered and also i had a for loop for grid view in which a qty textbox now if i enter 5 qty random six digit code had to generate for every qty with different 3 digit and 3 fix digit here's the code

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string text3 = textBox1.Text;
string text4 = "";
char[] array = text3.ToCharArray();
foreach (char c in array)
{
    int ascii = (int)c;
    //ascii = ((((ascii / 37 + 657) / 12) - 582) / 11);
    ascii += 23;
    text4 += Convert.ToChar(ascii).ToString();
}

//text4 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(text4);


textBox2.Text = rnd.Next().ToString() + text4.ToString();


}
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < int.Parse(qtytxt.Text); i++)
{
int j = i + 1;

dt.Rows.Add(label5.Text, comboBox1.Text, j, ratetxt.Text, Sizetxt.Text);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: And what is wrong, what is your question?
This piece of code is not a verifiable example, for instance, dt is not defined anywhere.. so no one can copy paste and test, for instance.
Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you trying to combine 3 user entered digits with 3 random ones to create a 6 digit number? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @rmjoia - the textbox and datagrid are to do with the presentation of the data. From the question's title he's not having any trouble with that. The issue seems to be something to do with generating the data itself. So, yes, you're right, they're not necessary, however, it does seem a little pedantic...

Comment: yes, maybe that is, its only the rules to ask questions, and thanks for telling me the purpose of the text-boxes and data-grid I totally missed that. thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @rmjoia - look in code textbox1 is taking a number which a had first converted in ascii adding +23 with it and decoded in character and the output is something like this "456HIJ" in which first 3 digit "456" is random and "HIJ" is number which i had entered in textbox1 "123" now the problem is i'm able to generate this for single number but what i want is if i had entered 5 qty in qtytextbox this six digit code generate every time new with fix last three digit and random first three digit..

Comment: @Gareth - yes dude i'm trying to combine 3 user entered digits with 3 random ones to create a 6 digit number which i did but only once a want to loop in with the my qtytextbox.. and i'm new to stackoverflow so don't judge the people to soon i known i'm new to coding "pedantic" seriously dude..:D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  Random rng = new Random();
    int number = rng.Next(100,1000);
    string text3 = textBox1.Text;
    string text4 =number+text3 ;
    string actualNumber=int.Parse(text4);
```